# Why does a custom adapter require a resource?

Tags: android

I'm more of a C++ developer and have just recently started Android development. While learning about Custom adapters for `ListView` one think struck me.

If you look at the constructors of ArrayAdapter, all of them require a resource which points to the layout. [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

I guess passing a layout is helpful when I'm using the default `ArrayAdapter` class.

But since I can `@Override` the `getView` method of `ArrayAdapter` in my own class, and manually inflate the view by passing the resource id, then why does the `ArrayAdapter` require a resource id on all its constructors?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //In the below line I'm passing the resource id to the inflate method
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you directly extend the `BaseAdapter` you can handle the layout inflation by your own. However the `ArrayAdapter` needs the resources to get the items and to inflate the item layouts. What it exactly does depends a little on your actual code.

I would recommend that you take a look at the source code of the [`ArrayAdapter`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java). That might help you.

A little off topic you should really recycle the views you can see how that is done also in the [ArrayAdapters source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L365), if you don't you would create dozens of elements which are not required.

Comment: But using a `BaseAdapter` I won't be able to remove and get items from my list directly. That's why I wanted to use an `ArrayAdapter`. But I guess it won't be a problem to pass anything in the constructor and then implement `getView` correctly ?

Comment: You should keep that list in your adapter implementation. Don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on every change if not the UI meight not update.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but what i said is correct or not? That I can pass anything in the resource field in the constructor and then handle the view properly in `getView` ?

Comment: Yes of cause that is possible too.